# Query to select days until a certain date

Tags: mysql, date

Either my brain isn't functioning the way it should today or this is actually a hard thing to do.

I've got the following table containing my users.

```
id    | name     | birthdate     |
------+----------+------------
1     | John     | 1990-08-27
2     | Jane     | 1985-08-29
3     | Joe      | 1985-08-31
```

`birthdate` is a `date` column in the above table.

I'd like to get the users that have their birthday today or in previous days including the weekend.

I've come no further than the following attempt:

```
SELECT
*
FROM users
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(users.birthdate, '%d-%m') IN (
    '29-08',
    '28-08',
    '27-08',
    '26-08'
)
```

Can any of you help me out with a query?

Comment: how many previous days?

Comment: Until and including last saturday.

Comment: And is birthdate a date column or varchar?

Comment: It's a date column. I should've included that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you want. First it translates the user's birthdate to the current year:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()), DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '-%m-%d')), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

then it sees if that date is between today (`CURRENT_DATE()`) and last Saturday:

```
CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) - 5 + 7) % 7 DAY
```

Full query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()), DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '-%m-%d')), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN
    CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) - 5 + 7) % 7 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71573/3)

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Dates in mysql always make my head hurt! :)

Comment: Using weekdays especially as you have to be careful with modulo arithmetic since it can return negative numbers which give you the opposite effect you are after!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE DATE(users.birthdate + INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(users.birthdate)) YEAR)
      BETWEEN
      DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY)
      AND
      DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY);
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71573/7

Answer (score 1):

use `NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(birthdate) +2 DAY` get last Saterday Date.

Then use `day` and `month` function to get the day and month number, then check in where clause.

- `month(birthdate)` is the same as `NOW()` month,
- `day` number from last Saturday to `NOW()`

You can try this.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  birthdate DATE
);


INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'John' , '1990-08-27');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2,'Jane' , '1985-08-29');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (22,'Joe' , '1985-05-31');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (33,'Joe' , '1985-08-11');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3,'Joe' , '1985-08-31');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE 
  month(birthdate) = month(NOW())
AND
   day(birthdate) between day(NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(birthdate) +2 DAY) and day(NOW())
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb401e/1/0)**:

```
| id | name |  birthdate |
|----|------|------------|
|  1 | John | 1990-08-27 |
|  2 | Jane | 1985-08-29 |
```

Comment: Will this work for every time of the year? How about if i would run this on the 2th of january?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) this will give you date including saturday

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE day(users.birthdate)>=day(curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) and <=day(curdate()) and (month(users.birthdate)=month(curdate()) or month(users.birthdate)=month(curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())))
```

Comment: This works at the moment but will not work at the beginning of the month, will it?